# SAP Webdynpro Canvas not displaying in Chrome, rendering partially in Firefox. Any suggestions please

Tags: canvas, chrome, browser

I built a canvas app using SAP webDynpro and it displayed and renders correctly in IE, partially displayed in Firefox and nothing displayed in Chrome. Anyone came across this please share their thoughts.

**What is currently working:**

Canvas developed using SAP WebDynPro and SAP WebGUI for HTML (Netweaver) both are working fine in IE.

**Issues:**

1. Canvas developed using SAP WebDynPro and SAP WebGUI for HTML (Netweaver) both not working in Chrome.
2. Canvas developed using SAP WebGUI for HTML (Netweaver) worked partially in Firefox

**In Chrome:**

[image]

**In Firefox:**

[image]

**In Internet Explorer:**

[image]